# How can I display the login/logoutbutton(); in the html title?

Tags: php, html, steam-web-api

I'm using the CMS webSPELL and want to display a new site. I am using `newsite.php`, `templates/newsite.html` and `template/title_newsite.html`.

The user should be able login with steam, if they aren't already logged in.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
 loginbutton();
}
```

How can I display the `loginbutton()` when the user is logged out and the `logoutbutton()` when the user is logged in? I want the button to be displayed in the `title_newsite.html`.

Comment: PHP does not run in files with the `.html` extension (normally) So this may not be possible

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need a new site, because you can handle to show html for logged in and html for logged out user on one site.

Here is a way to do that:

You need a session_start at the beginning of the page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Use this to show the logout button when you are logged in and to show the login button when you are logged out. You have to place it at the position where to button is located and replace LOGOUT BUTTON and LOGIN BUTTON with your HTML of the buttons.

```
<?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
                    echo ' LOUGOUT BUTTON HTML';

                }else{

                    echo ' LOGIN BUTTON HTML';
?>
```

Here is a perfect tutorial for all your needs:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC9GaXkdxF8